# criar uma tela de busca

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estou dando sequência em uma aplicação em ASP.Net MVC e preciso fazer uma tela de busca.

### A questão é a seguinte:

Criei uma tabela onde os usuários cadastram suas habilidades.

Preciso de uma `view` onde terá um campo texto onde a pessoa digitará por exemplo: "Costura". Clica em buscar e a aplicação deve retornar todas os usuários que tem a palavra "Costura" dentro do campo habilidades da tabela.

### Como implementar isso?

É como esses campos de pesquisa que temos em todos os sites. Acredito ser bem simples, mas não sei por onde começar.

Gostaria de no controller fazer um `select ... where... like '%@PALAVRADIGITADA%'` só que não sei a sintaxe para passar essa variável e tal.

Se alguém puder me dar uma luz, desde já agradeço.

Comment: Qual tipo de acesso você faz ao seu banco, SQLConnection ou com Entity ?

Comment: Você pode colocar na sua pergunta trechos do seu código já começado?

Comment: Cara vou colocar como comentário, mas olha esse link, que é do site oficial do asp.net mvc, ou até o asp.net também. Nesse link tem uma busca muito fácil de fazer, e dá um norte bem legal e dessa maneira você pode seguir adiante ! [Segue o link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/examining-the-edit-methods-and-edit-view). Siga esse exemplo do @HarryPotter também pra ter outra noção de como fazer !

Answer (score 3):

Exemplo com [`Entity Framework`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/)

Crie um *Controller* e coloque dois *métodos* com o nome de **Pesquisa**. O método *Pesquisa* decorado com `HttpGet` responderá as requisições `Get` e o decorado com `HttpPost` responderá pelas requisições `Post`. Quanto clicar no botão vai para o método *Pesquisa* decorado com `HttpPost`, que possui um paramentro texto que é enviado do formulário `Html`.

***Controler***

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ModelDb db;
    public HomeController()
    {
        db = new ModelDb();
    }

    ~HomeController()
    {
        db.Dispose();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Pesquisa()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Pesquisa(string texto)
    {
        return View(db.Pessoas.Where(x => x.Nome.Contains(texto)).OrderBy(x => x.Nome));
    }
}
```

***View:***

```cs
@model IEnumerable<WebApp.Models.Pessoas>
@{ Layout = null; }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Pesquisa</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
         @using (Html.BeginForm())
         {
             <p>Digite o nome</p>
             <input type="text" name="texto" id="texto" placeholder="Digite a pesquisa" />
             <div><button type="submit">Filtrar</button></div>   
         }
    </div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>Nome</td>
        </tr>
        @{
            if (Model != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@item.PessoaId</td>
                        <td>@item.Nome</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        }
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Ao clicar no botão Filtrar ele vai para o método *Pergunta* com paramento **texto** e fará um filtro (`SQL like` *pelo nome da entidade Pessoas*) e enviará o resultado para a mesma tela.